# How to transfer some information from one CSV to another CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two CSV files
one large CSV file (Stock.csv) that contains all the information and another one contains partial information(Sold.csv)

```
Example of the large CSV file(Stock.csv)
    Item_No       Price     
    1             20        
    2             10        
    3             9.99      
    4             11  
    5             13
    6             11
    7             7.99
```

the other CSV file contains only the sold items by Item_No with no price) which are now needed

```
Example of the other CSV file(Sold.csv)
    Item_No       Price 
    1             
    4      
    7
```

as you can see it only contains the Item_No , how can I add the price of each Item_No (The file contains more than 30000 items, doing it manually will take ages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("Stock.csv", sep=r"\s+")  # <-- adjust separator accordingly
df2 = pd.read_csv("Sold.csv", sep=r"\s+")

df2["Price"] = df2["Item_No"].map(df1.set_index("Item_No")["Price"])
print(df2)
df2.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
   Item_No  Price
0        1  20.00
1        4  11.00
2        7   7.99
```

and creates `output.csv`.

Comment: I got an error KeyError: 'Item_No' I don't know why

Comment: @ray Try `print(df1)` or `print(df2)` and check if you have the columns there (make sure there aren't any whitespaces before and/or after the column names)

Comment: I made sure of everything , no whitespace anywhere, and all the columns are there but it gives the same error

Comment: @ray Try `print(df1.columns)` and `print(df2.columns)` and make sure `Item_No` is there (with correct upper/lower cases).

Comment: printing works fine if it is placed before df2["Price"] = df2["Item_No"].map(df1.set_index("Item_No")["Price"])  , this specific line has the error

Comment: the outputs are Index(['Item_No,Price'], dtype='object')
Index(['Item_No,Price'], dtype='object')

Comment: @ray The error is that you need to adjust the separator when loading the csv (to `,`) You have just one column `'Item_No,Price'` (note: this is just one string)

Comment: this seems to solve the keyerror problem . however, another error ( Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects) any idea ?

Comment: @ray Does your `Stock.csv` contain duplicities in `Item_No`? If yes, drop them before doing the mapping.

Comment: Works perfectly !! thank you very much for helping !!